# Creating a new File in Scala with PrintWriter

Tags: scala

I have created a function to create a file.
My goal is to  pass in a json string and return a new File with the contents of the json string passed into it. I am calling this function in another function as:

```
val jsonFile: File = JsonCreate.getJsonFile(jsonString)
```

So far, the way I have is as follows:
I create a new file that does not exist and I call it "myJson.json"

I then create a PrintWriter object, with the idea of using this to create my final file. So, I read the contents of the json string, into a StringBuffer, and then over into the PrintWriter. With this done, I hope to have a file myJson.json with the contents of the passed in Json string.

I am not so pleased with the result of my efforts so far. For example, I am not sure if I have used Option the way it is supposed to be used. I am not pleased with the way I am using vars. 
 If I declare a val inside a try, I am not able to access it in the finally. So I go the Java way and put the PrinterWriter Option variable outside.This is a code smell I do not like. 
 How can I shorten it and still retain the right try catch and finally, close the resources, etc.

This is my first attempt at writing this function:

```
import java.io._
import java.util.Scanner

object JsonCreate{
     def createFile(jsonString: String): File = {

        var tmpFile = new File("myJson.json")
        var outFileOpt: Option[PrintWriter] = Some(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFile, true)))


        try {
          //Update: Corrected the value of the Scanner parameter
          val inFile: Scanner = new Scanner(jsonString)
          while(inFile.hasNextLine) {
            val strBuf = new StringBuffer(inFile.nextLine())
            println("Contents of String Buffer is: " + strBuf)
            outFileOpt.get.print(strBuf)
          }

        }catch {
          case fnfex: FileNotFoundException => fnfex.printStackTrace()
          case ioex: IOException => ioex.printStackTrace()

        } finally {
          outFileOpt.get.close()
        }

        tmpFile

      }


}
```

Comment: Your method does not use `jsonString` at all. What is `finalJson`, it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I have made the correction. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to store the file in an `Option`. Using `Option.get` is usually a sign that you're doing something wrong, because you assume the option is set.

Then if you already have a string, there is no reason why you would want to scan it, write into another buffer etc. Just write it directly into the file, using for example `FileOutputStream.`

Intercepting exceptions to print them out is not a good practice. Let them propagate to the caller.

```
import java.io.{File, FileOutputStream}

def writeTextFile(f:File, contents: String, encoding: String = "UTF-8"): Unit = {
  val fos = new FileOutputStream(f)
  try {
    fos.write(contents.getBytes(encoding))
  } finally {
    fos.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: That is what I vaguely thought. The use of the get was looking not right somehow but I could not put my finger on it, until you clarified it.

Comment: You are assigning `outFileOpt` only once. Therefore it doesn't need to be a `var` but only a `val`. Then you see that it's `Some` and defined, therefore the `Option` does not have any purpose.

Comment: In your function, how would I modify that to return a File because I need that in my calling function. Or what is the best way to return a File with the freshly written contents into it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment on outFileOpt needing to be a var. I am going to try and rewrite the function based on what you said

Comment: If you define `f: File` inside the function—right before `fos`—make the function's return type `File` instead of `Unit`, put `f` in the last line to make it the return value. `def writeTextFile(contents: String): File = { val f = new File(???); val fos = ...; try { ... } finally { ... }; f }`